# r2dbc-mssql generatedKey return type numeric

Tags: sql-server, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

The sample stack: Spring Data R2dbc 1.0.0.RELEASE, R2dbc Mssql 0.8, the complete code is [here](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/tree/master/boot-data-r2dbc-mysql).

The init script:

```sql
use tempdb;

IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.posts', N'U') IS NULL
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE posts (
        id BIGINT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
        title VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
        content VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
        createdAt DATETIME,
        updatedAt DATETIME
    )
END;
```

When saving the data and getting the generated keys from `DataInitializer`.

```java
@Component
@Slf4j
class DataInitializer {

    private final DatabaseClient databaseClient;

    public DataInitializer(DatabaseClient databaseClient) {
        this.databaseClient = databaseClient;
    }

    @EventListener(value = ContextRefreshedEvent.class)
    public void init() {
        log.info("start data initialization...");
        this.databaseClient.delete().from("posts")
                .then().
                and(

                        this.databaseClient.insert()
                                .into("posts")
                                //.nullValue("id", Integer.class)
                                .value("title", "First post title")
                                .value("content", "Content of my first post")
                                .map((r, m) -> r.get( 0, BigDecimal.class)).all()
                                .log()
                )
                .thenMany(
                        this.databaseClient.select()
                                .from("posts")
                                .orderBy(Sort.by(desc("id")))
                                .as(Post.class)
                                .fetch()
                                .all()
                                .log()
                )
                .subscribe(null, null, () -> log.info("initialization is done..."));
    }

}
```

If I use `Integer` or `Long` instead of `BigDecimal` in the line `.map((r, m) -> r.get( 0, BigDecimal.class)).all()`, it will raise an error indicates **Cannot decode value of type [java.lang.Long], name [GENERATED_KEYS] server type [numeric]**, it is not `bigint` as defined in the schema script, I have to use a `BigDecimal` to make it work.

Comment: The R2DBC driver does not implement conversion from `BIGINT` (`numeric`) to a primitive type yet. Can you file a ticket at https://github.com/r2dbc/r2dbc-mssql/issues?

Comment: Created issue [r2dbc-mssql#130](https://github.com/r2dbc/r2dbc-mssql/issues/130)